# How to get Excel to use digit grouping separator (thousand separator) universally?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Digit grouping separator is already set in my regional settings

[image]

But excel doesn't show numbers like that. How can I get excel to do that everywhere **including the average number in status bar**.

[image]

I don't wanna have to select and format each sheet to show numbers like that.

Comment: You can do that pretty easily using ``Ctrl+A`` and then selecting the ``,`` style in numbers tab. Why can't you just do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers entered or pasted into an Excel cell use the General format by default. This doesn't use thousand separators because that wouldn't always be appropriate. The numbers you've entered or pasted might be identifiers, or some multi digit number for which it wouldn't be appropriate to separate the digits. The General format is the safe option as it tries to make as few assumptions as possible.

For example, I frequently have columns that have a four-digit year in them. If these were automatically formatted to 2,020 (for this year), it would be very annoying!

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd> to format selected cells to the "Comma Style" format, which will usually use thousands separator and two decimal places. In Excel 365, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will achieve the same thing.

EDIT:

A workaround is to create a macro in your Personal macro workbook and assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

If you haven't used the personal macro workbook before, the easiest way to get at it is to record a new macro and select it from the drop-down.

Click "Record Macro" from the "Code" group on the "Developer" tab of the ribbon, then use the drop-down in the dialog box. You can give it a shortcut at the same time:

[image]

Record the step you usually take to format in the way you want.

I clicked "Comma style" then removed the decimals then I made the column a bit wider to make sure it worked on a large number I had in my test data. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the code editor, and saw this:

```
Sub MyFormat()
'
' MyFormat Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.0_);_(* (#,##0.0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 24.71
End Sub
```

I don't need all of that. Just the third line, so I edited it so I had this:

```
Sub MyFormat()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

End Sub
```

Now I have that macro in the Personal macro workbook, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will apply that format to whatever I have selected.

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut but using that I still have to go over the formatting window and remove those extra decimal. I was looking for a universal setting so you don't have to do it every time. This Uservoice page is exactly what I was looking for:
https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/33545875-number-format-thousand-separator-and-no-decimals

Comment: p.s. choose your shortcut carefully! Ctrl+G is normally "Go to". But I don't use that much, so it seemed OK to me.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of workaround. I believe this would be the answer till Microsoft itself makes that option available.